# Is an arrayList in Java an array or a list?

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

Recently I worked with arrayLists in a Java program I had to write for school. I was simply wondering; is an arrayList an array or a list, or both?

Comment: Check the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). Voting to close.

Comment: It is a List that is implemented using an array.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because a simple check to Java SE API would answer the question.

Comment: @TeresaCarrigan is correct.  A List can be thought of as an abstraction while an Array is more of an implementation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You ask:

> is an arrayList an array or a list, or both?

---

It **is** a List through inheritance, and it is **composed** with an array.

---

It implements the `java.util.List<T>` interface and thus passes the "is-a" test for this. This means that anything you can do with a List, including calling all of List public methods, you can do with an ArrayList.

It's data model however is backed by an array, and so it contains an array by composition. So this means that while it has some array-like behaviors obtained from the underlying array, you can't call array methods or obtain array fields on it directly. For instance, you cannot obtain items from the ArrayList using array indices. i.e., this won't work: `myArrayList[i]`, but you can call this indirectly via ArrayList's `get(int i)` method. And also you can't get a `length` field from it, but you can get it indirectly from its `size()` method. Also, note that obtaining data from an ArrayList will follow the same limiting big O behavior as that of an array.

Answer (score 3):

`ArrayList` implements the List interface

See doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

If you look at the ArrayList inner implementation, you will notice that it is wrapped around an array.

Here is the implementation for your reference:  http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java

For instance here is one constructor implementation:

when you create a new ArrayList with initial capacity

```
public More ...ArrayList(int initialCapacity) {
         super();
        if (initialCapacity < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Capacity: "+
                                                initialCapacity);
        this.elementData = new Object[initialCapacity];
     }
```

Comment: Going to the source code -- nice! 1+

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList is an implementation of List, backed by an array
All optional operations including adding, removing, and replacing elements are supported.

All elements are permitted, including null.

[10 examples of using ArrayList in java](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/05/example-of-arraylist-in-java-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` implements from the `List` interface

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An ArrayList is a object that implements the List interface.

Unlike arrays, you can add/remove/get elements much more easy than convencional array. ArrayLists don't have size limits, so you can put a larger list of elements in the list.

This class manipulates an array with default size in the background, so if you need to remove or add an element, it creates a new copy of the array (with a larger size if needed) and add in the array object.